# How to position a child element to top of the parent using CSS

Tags: css

In my situation there are two boxes and each boxes have a small child box. Both the parent and child boxes are positioned absolute. My requirement is to position the small box inside first box to stack on top of the second big box. How can we achieve using z-index. or is there any other way we can achieve this.

**HTML**

```
<div id="boxes">
  <div id="dd-demo-1" class="dd-demo">
    <strong>A</strong>
    <br>position:
    <span>absolute</span>
    <br>z-index:
    <span>12</span>
    <div id="div1">
      <strong>a</strong>
      <br>position:
      <span>absolute</span>
      <br>z-index:
      <span>14</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="dd-demo-2" class="dd-demo">
    <strong>B</strong>
    <br>position:
    <span>absolute</span>
    <br>z-index:
    <span>not set</span>
    <div id="div2">
      <strong>b</strong>
      <br>position:
      <span>absolute</span>
      <br>z-index:
      <span>not set</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#dd-demo-1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 12;
}

#div1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 14;
  left: 42px;
  top: 165px;
}

#dd-demo-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 235px;
  z-index: 12;
}

#div2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 29px;
  z-index: 12;
}

.dd-demo {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px inset #ccc;
  color: #fff;
  height: 14em;
  width: 15em;
  padding-top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 12;
}

#div1,
#Aafield {
  background-color: #00ffff;
  color: #000000;
}

#dd-demo-1,
#Afield {
  background-color: #0066ff;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#dd-demo-2,
#Bfield {
  background-color: #006600;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#div2,
#Bbfield {
  background-color: #00ff00;
  color: #000000;
}

#div1,
#div2,
#div3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em auto;
  height: 6em;
  width: 11em;
  border: 1px outset #ccc;
}
```

Codepen Link: https://codepen.io/nhjsph/full/NzgPVP/

Answer (score 0):

I have changed  some part of your CSS.

Updated these styles

```
#dd-demo-1 {
  z-index: 12;
}

#div1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```css
#dd-demo-1 {
  z-index: 12;
}

#div1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin: 0 !important;
}

#dd-demo-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 235px;
  z-index: 12;
}

#div2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 29px;
  z-index: 12;
}

.dd-demo {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px inset #ccc;
  color: #fff;
  height: 14em;
  width: 15em;
  padding-top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 12;
}

#div1,
#Aafield {
  background-color: #00ffff;
  color: #000000;
}

#dd-demo-1,
#Afield {
  background-color: #0066ff;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#dd-demo-2,
#Bfield {
  background-color: #006600;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#div2,
#Bbfield {
  background-color: #00ff00;
  color: #000000;
}

#div1,
#div2,
#div3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em auto;
  height: 6em;
  width: 11em;
  border: 1px outset #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxes">
  <div id="dd-demo-1" class="dd-demo">
    <strong>A</strong>
    <br>position:
    <span>absolute</span>
    <br>z-index:
    <span>12</span>

    <div id="div1">
      <strong>a</strong>
      <br>position:
      <span>absolute</span>
      <br>z-index:
      <span>14</span>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="dd-demo-2" class="dd-demo">
    <strong>B</strong>
    <br>position:
    <span>absolute</span>
    <br>z-index:
    <span>not set</span>
    <div id="div2">
      <strong>b</strong>
      <br>position:
      <span>absolute</span>
      <br>z-index:
      <span>not set</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change like this:**

```
#div1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 14;
  left: 42px;
  top: 165px; <--------Removed
  bottom: 0;  <--------Added
  margin-bottom: 0!important;
  //If you do not want space between small box and big box.
}
```

```css
#dd-demo-1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 12;
}

#div1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 14;
  left: 42px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0!important;
}

#dd-demo-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 235px;
  z-index: 12;
}

#div2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 12;
}

.dd-demo {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px inset #ccc;
  color: #fff;
  height: 14em;
  width: 15em;
  padding-top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 12;
}

#div1,
#Aafield {
  background-color: #00ffff;
  color: #000000;
}

#dd-demo-1,
#Afield {
  background-color: #0066ff;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#dd-demo-2,
#Bfield {
  background-color: #006600;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#div2,
#Bbfield {
  background-color: #00ff00;
  color: #000000;
}

#div1,
#div2,
#div3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em auto;
  height: 6em;
  width: 11em;
  border: 1px outset #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxes">
  <div id="dd-demo-1" class="dd-demo">
    <strong>A</strong>
    <br>position:
    <span>absolute</span>
    <br>z-index:
    <span>12</span>
    <div id="div1">
      <strong>a</strong>
      <br>position:
      <span>absolute</span>
      <br>z-index:
      <span>14</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="dd-demo-2" class="dd-demo">
    <strong>B</strong>
    <br>position:
    <span>absolute</span>
    <br>z-index:
    <span>not set</span>
    <div id="div2">
      <strong>b</strong>
      <br>position:
      <span>absolute</span>
      <br>z-index:
      <span>not set</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```